# Java; access comment in code

Tags: java, javadoc, dry

It may be strange. I have some text as comment of a method and I can link to that like this:

> /** {@link com.mypackage.YetAnotherClass#myMethod(String)}. */

But I want to use that text as part of a String in code.It seems that I have to choices:

1. Copy and paste text from comment to code.
2. Create class with static filed and use that in both comment and code in other classes.

First option violates `DRY` and second complicates code by creating a new class.Is there another way to use text of comments in code?

Comment: choose second and place your string inside a static field. use `@value` in your javadoc to include its value in your documentation.

Comment: Why do you want it in a comment?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Comments are not included in the compiled class. At all. You would need a tool to extract them from source (or previously generated javadocs) or otherwise *transform the source* prior-compile to embed the comments within something that does exist post-compilation. In general compiled should not 'need' comments - explaining the actual use case better may net better (and more focused) replies..

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I understand what you are doing, but you can reuse some text string in both comments and code like this:

```
public class A {
    /**
     * {@link B#method()}.
     */
    void method() {
        System.out.println(B.comment);
    }
}


public class B {
    public static final String comment = "This is some comment";
    /**
     * Comment: {@value #comment}
     */
    void method() {
    }
}
```

(I wouldn't say that reusing phrases or words are violating DRY though...)